# Maven copying Tomcat JARs into webapp WEB-INF/lib directory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a very simple webapp published as a WAR file, being developed in Eclipse. I'm using m2e for dependency management. My project, in the `Project Facets` tab, has the `Dynamic Web Module` enabled, along with `Java`. In addition, under my `Deployment Assembly` I have the Maven dependencies listed, but no inclusion/exclusion options:

[image]

My WAR builds fine, and runs fine in Eclipse. *However*, the `Dynamic Web Module` seems to be resulting in my WAR file containing a number of Tomcat JARs, in addition to all my other dependencies:

[image]

I was able to remove `tomcat-catalina-7.0.30.jar` (not pictured) by including in my POM.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

But it seems there must be a way to tell Maven that the entire Tomcat *container* will be provided at runtime. I don't want to add ~20 `provided` entries to remove the rest of them.

Comment: Why do you have tomcat-xyz.jar dependencies at all? Please show your pom.xml.

Comment: @Stefan I have no idea - that's what I'm trying to figure out, and fix.

Comment: I agree with Stefan, there is likely no reason at all to have a Tomcat dependency in your hierarchy. Please show the entire _pom.xml_ or just try removing the dependency entirely and test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the POMs of your project. Somewhere, someone added them without the proper `scope`.

In Eclipse, you can use the POM editor. There is a set of tabs at the *bottom* of the editor. One reads "Dependency Hierarchy". Here you can search for "tomcat" and m2e will tell you which POMs contain such a dependency.

Comment: You were completely right, the extra *other* JARs should have have tipped me off. I forgot to add `provided` scope to my `tomcat7-maven-plugin` used for deployment. Hence all the wagon JARs in addition to the Tomcat ones.